# Custom Grouping with Telerik Grid for MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, telerik

I wish to create a Telerik grid which can be grouped by different fields in the table, but I'm running into quite a problem - Telerik only allows me to designate a property to group by, and then that's it.

What I want to do is to partly be able to designate the title of the group. Instead of "Current Index: 9" I might want to remove the property name (Current Index) and replace the number by getting the value for it in a dictionary.

Also, say I want to sort by a date - Then I'll be wanting to sort only by year, month and day, and not by the full extent of the datetime down to the very last millisecond (results in separate groups for every object).

Is there any way to achieve something like this at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my conumdrum by using ClientTemplates (Ajax binding) and custom properties in my viewmodel.